# The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got  The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error when try to retrieve linked-in API but some time it's working and sometime it's giving 500 error. Some of the industry data i can able to retrieve from linked in API but most of the industry not working it's giving 500 error Can anyone help me on this

Comment: No.  A 500 error means *"There was an error on the server"*, and it will not tell you any more than that.  Show us what API call you are making, and what data you are using and we *may* be able to help you.  It's most likely that you're asking for something in the wrong way.

Comment: Services can always fail. Client applications should be able to handle such failures and eg retry an operation, retry after a delay, call a different service etc. You can use a library like Polly to make this easier

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't think LinkedIn would be overly impressed at someone repeatedly retrying API calls that return 500 errors.  Retry policy handlers, like Polly, aren't meant for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319924/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: @Archer there's nothing wrong with trying 3 times with 1 sec delay between them. Even small sites use load balancers which means if one call fails, the *next* one will go to another server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree with that, but that's not what you advised the guy who's asking *"how do I fix a 500 error on someone else's server"* ;)